# Get month name from Date in jooq

Tags: mysql, postgresql, jooq, jooq-sbt-plugin

How can I generate the name of the month (e.g: Oct/October) from this date object in jooq?

> date- "2019-11-01 00:00:00"

want to extract month name from date.

output- November

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the month number using [`DSL.month(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#month(org.jooq.Field)).

jOOQ doesn't vendor specific support date time formatting functions out of the box. You could use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) to use vendor specific functionality, such as:

```java
// MySQL
public static Field<String> formatMonth(Field<Timestamp> dateColumn) {
  return DSL.field("date_format({0}, '%M')", SQLDataType.VARCHAR, dateColumn);
}

// PostgreSQL
public static Field<String> formatMonth(Field<Timestamp> dateColumn) {
  return DSL.field("to_char({0}, 'Month')", SQLDataType.VARCHAR, dateColumn);
}
```

If you need to do this several times and don't always want to worry about vendor agnosticity, you can create a [`CustomField`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/):

```java
public static Field<String> formatMonth(Field<Timestamp> dateColumn) {
  return new CustomField<String>("format_month", SQLDataType.VARCHAR) {
    @Override
    public void accept(Context<?> ctx) {
      switch (ctx.family()) {
        case MYSQL:
          ctx.visit(DSL.field("date_format({0}, '%M')", SQLDataType.VARCHAR, dateColumn));
          break;
        case POSTGRES:
          ctx.visit(DSL.field("to_char({0}, 'Month')", SQLDataType.VARCHAR, dateColumn));
          break;
        default:
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Dialect not supported: " + ctx.family());
      }
    }
  };
}
```